# When to use a Directory or a Database?

Tags: database, directory, ldap

When does it make sense to use a Directory over a Database (and vice versa).

It becomes even more confusing given that most directories have a database backend.

Comment: You should look at this  http://www.htmlgoodies.com/primers/database/article.php/3478121/To-Use-or-Not-to-Use-a-Database-That-is-the-Question.htm, maybe you will find some elements of answer.
For me you have to use a database as soon as you have to access data quickly and often, if you have to manage a lot of information..could you give us a more precise context?

Comment: Most directories have a database backend ... so this becomes even more confusing.

Comment: What do you mean by directory? I'm not sure I get it:)

Comment: @JeremyD An example of a directory would be LDAP.

Comment: @user371320,  LDAP is the protocol most often used to "speak" to a directory. As such, what you stated isn't technically correct.

Comment: @nickb Understood, just trying to point Jeremy in the right direction.  I didn't mean to introduce more confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a [good write up](http://blogs.oracle.com/treydrake/entry/ldap_vs_relational_database) of when to use a Directory over a Database, written by a Product Manager for Oracle.